# Create a shopping list using a GTIN 8 code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a shopping list using GTIN-8 in python. My problem is that I can't seem to find a way to get the user to input a number (a GTIN-8 code from the options below) and then get the program to get that number, search for it in a given database and then display what item that number is equal to.

For example, if the user inputs in `12345670 2`, the program would output

```
12345670    Hammer    2    4.50
Subtotal                    9.00
```

My code is as follows:

```
print("Hi There! Welcome to sSpecialists!")
print("To start shopping, note down what you want to buy and how much of it")
print("Here are the purchasable items")

print("~~~~~")

print("12345670 is a hammer (£4.50)")
print("87654325 is a screw driver (£4.20)")
print("96385272 is a pack of 5 iron screws (£1.20)")
print("74185290 is pack of 20 100mm bolts (£1.99)")
print("85296374 is a pack of 6 walkers crisps (£1)")
print("85274198 is haribo pack (£1)")
print("78945616 is milk (£0.88)")
print("13246570 is a bottle of evian water (£0.99)")
print("31264570 is kitkat original (£0.50)")
print("91537843 is a cadbury bar (£1)")

print("~~~~~")

response = input("To view more of our items type more, else no: ")
if response == 'more':
    print("~~~~~")
    print("45762147 is a 20 pack of sausages (£2.49)")
    print("19348629 is a toy lion (£1.20)")
    print("34821565 is a pack of 7 beef burgers (£1.20)")
    print("48613545 is pack of 10 fish fingers (£1.99)")
    print("46729811 is 500ml of heinz mayonnaise (£1)")
    print("48613255 is 500ml of heinz ketchup (£1)")
    print("31750677 is youghurt (£0.88)")
    print("13246570 is 500ml of tropical juice (£0.99)")
    print("76136948 is adult bmx bike (£499)")
    print("76153242 is a sony ps4 (£249)")
    print("46821799 is adult bmw i8 (£89,000)")
    print("01352474 is a jar of pickles (£1)")
    print("98523153 is a 20 pack of adult diapers (£7)")
    print("18648515 is £20 psn card (£19.99)")

if response == 'no':
    print(" ")
print("Alright, now start typing what you want to order")
print("Include the amount with a spacing")
print("For example 12345670 2 would be two hammers")
print("And when you're done, type 'END' to finish")
print("Start your orders")
print(" ")

full_list = " "
orders = []
while full_list != "END":
    full_list = input("Enter your order: ")
    if full_list != "END":
        orders.append(full_list)
```

I need to input a method of getting the user-inputted GTIN code and translating it back to the user as the written item. This is Python 3.5.

Comment: Your code is just a bunch of print statements - which is not database driven. I would suggest you look into something like sqlite and basic database design. There are tons of examples on google which will lead you in the right direction. Otherwise this question really isn't for SO.

Answer (score -1):

```
BOARD_SIZE = 8

class BailOut(Exception):
    pass

def validate(queens):
    left = right = col = queens[-1]
    for r in reversed(queens[:-1]):
        left, right = left-1, right+1
        if r in (left, col, right):
            raise BailOut

def add_queen(queens):
    for i in range(BOARD_SIZE):
        test_queens = queens + [i]
        try:
            validate(test_queens)
            if len(test_queens) == BOARD_SIZE:
                return test_queens
            else:
                return add_queen(test_queens)
        except BailOut:
            pass
    raise BailOut

queens = add_queen([])
print queens
print "\n".join(". "*q + "Q " + ". "*(BOARD_SIZE-q-1) for q in queens)

33 lines: "Guess the Number" Game (edited) from http://inventwithpython.com

import random

guesses_made = 0

name = raw_input('Hello! What is your name?\n')

number = random.randint(1, 20)
print 'Well, {0}, I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.'.format(name)

while guesses_made < 6:

    guess = int(raw_input('Take a guess: '))

    guesses_made += 1

    if guess < number:
        print 'Your guess is too low.'

    if guess > number:
        print 'Your guess is too high.'

    if guess == number:
        break

if guess == number:
    print 'Good job, {0}! You guessed my number in {1} guesses!'.format(name, guesses_made)
else:
    print 'Nope. The number I was thinking of was {0}'.format(number)




Ur wlcm
```